# Accessing a server's output on EC2

Tags: logs, amazon-ec2

I've just been hired to do work on a company's existing website, which is running on EC2.

They gave me the proper credentials to `ssh` in and I got in successfully.

I found out that webpages are being served via the JavaScript task runner *Grunt*. Presumably, someone else started a terminal process which is serving the pages.

I'd like to access that terminal's output to start debugging how page are being served, and to be able to access debug lines that are being outputted there. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Have you ran `top` to see what process *Grunt* is and who started it?

Answer (score 1):

A network server is highly unlikely to be also a program with a terminal-based interface. It probably doesn't interact with a user at all, but rather either writes to its [standard output or standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) if it's designed as a component in a larger infrastructure, or emits log entries directly to the system logs if it's intended to be used as a network server on its own. If the program is writing to the standard streams then the normal way to start it would be to [redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) its output streams to a file.

So don't look for a terminal. Look for a log file. Where the log file is depends on how the program and the system have been configured.

You can run `ls -l /proc/1234/fd` where 1234 is the process ID to see what files the process has open. If you see a file, look there. If you see `/dev/log` or some other socket, that means the program is logging to the system logs. System logs are located in `/var/log` and the easiest way to see which file your program logs to is to cause it to emit a log message and see which file's modification time is updated.